# is there any way to split single field value into multiple column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have a situation where i supposed to display `columnar` fashion

im using this `query`

```
SELECT status, count(*) as total_
FROM companydata 
WHERE status = 'Not Emailed' or status = 'Not Emailed' or status = 'Email Sent' or status = 'Response Received' or status = 'Interested' or status =
'Not Interested'
GROUP BY status
```

it return something like this

```
   status               total_
-|--------------------|--------------------------
    Not Emailed         9562
 |   Interested       |   2
    Response Received     45
 |  Email Sent        |   3000
```

is there any way to make them look `columnar` fashion

```
Not Emailed    Interested    Response Received   Email Sent

9562             2               45                   3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter your original query to count conditionally

```
SELECT Count(CASE WHEN status = 'Not Emailed' THEN 1 END) AS `Not Emailed`,
       Count(CASE WHEN status = 'Email Sent' THEN 1 END) AS `Email Sent`,
       Count(CASE WHEN status = 'Response Received' THEN 1 END) AS `Response Received`,
       Count(CASE WHEN status = 'Not Interested' THEN 1 END) AS `Not Interested`
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  status IN ( 'Not Emailed', 'Not Emailed', 'Response Received', 'Interested', 'Not Interested' )
```

Alternatively instead of `COUNT` we can use `SUM` aggregate as well

```
Sum(CASE WHEN status = 'Not Emailed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Not Emailed`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an elaboration of prdp's answer.  In MySQL, I think the easiest method is:

```
SELECT SUM(status = 'Not Emailed') AS `Not Emailed`,
       SUM(status = 'Email Sent') AS `Email Sent`,
       SUM(status = 'Response Received') AS `Response Received`,
       SUM(status = 'Not Interested') AS `Not Interested`
FROM yourtable
WHERE  status IN ( 'Not Emailed', 'Not Emailed', 'Response Received', 'Interested', 'Not Interested' ) ;
```

`CASE` is also correct -- and portable to most databases.  This is just a convenient short-hand in MySQL.